# Find a subsequence of $f_n = n^{1/p} \chi_{[0, 1/n]}$ whose arithmetic mean converges strongly.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Find a subsequence of $f_n = n^{1/p} \chi_{[0, 1/n]}$ in $L^P$ whose arithmetic mean converges strongly.

**Attempt:**
To solve this problem we mainly have The Banach-Saks Theorem: Let $E$ be a measurable set and $1 < p < \infty$. Suppose $\{f_n\} \rightharpoonup f$ (weakly)in $L^p(E)$. Then there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ for which the sequence of arithmetic means converges strongly to $f$ in $L^p(E)$, that is,
$$\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \frac{f_{n_1}+f_{n_2}+...+f_{n_k}}{k}=f \text{ strongly in } L^p(E)$$

We know this $f_n$ converge weakly in $L^p$

Any help on how to find this subsequence? Thanks

Comment: I bet $n_k=2^k$ works. On $[0,1]$ you get a convergent geometric series divided by $k$, so that part tends to $0$ in norm. Split $[1,2^k]$ into subintervals $[2^j, 2^{j+1}]$. On each subinterval you can calculate exactly what the sum is...

Comment: I am clear on the first part. Not so clear what I have to do on second part(Split $[1,2^k]$ into subintervals $[2^j,2^{j+1}]$...)

Comment: You haven't spent much time thinking about it...

Comment: I am trying my best, and I appreciate your help, but again, I am not sure how to continue on you second part clue

Comment: And again, you haven't spent much time thinking about it. If $n_k=2^k$ then your sum is _constant_ on each interval $(2^j,2^{j+1}]$. Figure out what that constant is. Use that to find the norm of the sum.